# Question about G-Forces and Circular Motion on a Human Centrifuge

Tags: calculus, physics, classical-mechanics

I don't really understand what a G-force is and how it can be used to solve problems using the formula:
$$T=mv^2/r$$

T is tension, m is mass (in kg), v is velocity (m/s) and r is radius of the circle.

The question is as follows: To withstand g-forces of up to 10 g's pilots train on a human centrifuge.  In a human centrifuge, if the length of its arm is 12 m. what speed is the rider moving when he experiences 10g/s?

Now assume that an individual experiences 14g's, where the centrifuge is rotating at 1 rev/s.  How long will the centrifuge arm be?

Its not clear to me what exactly is the unit if a "g" and whether g/s is a speed or not.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "One-gee" is the acceleration equal to Earth's "surface gravity" acceleration $  \ g \ = \ 9.81 \ \frac{m}{sec^2} \  $ .  So "10 - g's" is equal to $ \ 98.1 \  \frac{m}{sec^2} \  $ , etc.  The "10 g/s" is not correct, though: it should just be an acceleration of 10 g .

Comment: if that's the case then where would your 98.1 fit into the equation above?  You have velocity being the closest thing and the only thing we know for sure is radius...

Comment: $ \ \frac{v^2}{r} \ $ is the centripetal acceleration, so that will be what you set equal to $ \ 98.1 \ \frac{m^2}{sec} \ $ .  You are given the radius of the centrifuge, so you can calculate the tangential speed $ \ v \ $ of the centrifuge capsule.  This will apply regardless of the mass of the capsule and passenger.